# reorder word with condition in array of string python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, list, sorting

I need to change order word in sentence after specific character/word found.

Example:

```
s = ["i", "dont", "like, "you"]
```

If `dont` is found then order be like this:

```
s_order = ["dont", "like", "you", "i"]
```

All the words before `dont` will be add/append into the last.

I already try using sorted method like this:

```
s_sorted = sorted(s, key=lambda x:(x!='dont', x))
```

But the words before `dont` append first instead of last:

```
s_sorted = ['dont', 'i', 'like', 'you']
```

Is there a best way to do this? Thanks.
Thank you for the helps.

Answer (score 1):

With simple slicing:

```
s = ["i", "dont", "like", "you"]
pos = s.index('dont')  # the position of the search word in sequence
res = s[pos:] + s[:pos]
print(res)   # ['dont', 'like', 'you', 'i']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily

```
s = ["i", "dont", "like", "you"]
split_target = "dont" 
split_idx = -1

for word_idx in range(len(s)):
     if s[word_idx] == split_target:
         split_idx = word_idx

s = s[split_idx:] + s[:split_idx]
```

what this code does is that it finds where to split the list, then takes the list from there on till the end and adds it to another list from the start to the split point

Comment: thanks for help and the explanation about the code :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
>>> l = s[s.index('dont'):]
>>> l + s[:len(s) - len(l)]
['dont', 'like', 'you', 'i']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deque for this purpose too, which has the inbuilt rotate method. it finds the position of where `dont` is and the rotates it based on the index. rotation to the left is done with a negative index and so hence the `-d.index('dont')`.

```
import collections
d = collections.deque(["i", "dont", "like", "you"]) 
d.rotate(-d.index('dont'))
print(d)
```

Output

```
deque(['dont', 'like', 'you', 'i'])
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution with `sorted()`:

```
s = ["i", "dont", "like", "you"]

print([word for _, word in sorted(enumerate(s), key=lambda k, i=s.index('dont'): k[0] < i)])
```

Prints:

```
['dont', 'like', 'you', 'i']
```